# Exception by loading TTF font into AssetManager

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx, truetype

Follwing this code example: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/extensions/FreeTypeFontLoaderTest.java

I'm trying to load **one single ttf file into the AssetManager with different parameters and different filenames**.

```
public class LoadingScreen implements Screen {

    private final GdxAsternets game;

    private float progress;

    public LoadingScreen(final GdxAsternets game){
        this.game = game;

        game.bitmapFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font/myFont.fnt"));

        queueAssets();
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        progress = 0f;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        update(delta);
    }

    private void update(float delta){
        progress = MathUtils.lerp(progress, game.assetManager.getProgress(), 0.1f);
        if(game.assetManager.update() && progress >= game.assetManager.getProgress()- 0.1f){
            game.setScreen(game.menuScreen);
        }
    }

    private void queueAssets(){
        //Fontloader/Filehandler
        FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
        game.assetManager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver));
        game.assetManager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".ttf", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));

        //load timer font
        FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter smallFontParams = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
        smallFontParams.fontFileName = "font/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf";
        smallFontParams.fontParameters.size = 40;
        game.assetManager.load("smallFont.ttf", BitmapFont.class, smallFontParams);

        //load game msg font
        FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter bigFontParams = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
        smallFontParams.fontFileName = "font/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf";
        smallFontParams.fontParameters.size = 85;
        game.assetManager.load("bigFont.ttf", BitmapFont.class, bigFontParams);
    }
    /**Overring methods...*/
}
```

Look up at the method **queueAssets()**. Quoting the link above me:**"The names of the fonts are arbitrary and are not pointing to a file disk"**. I've named the generated fonts "bigFont.ttf" and "smallFont.ttf" but it fails to load the assets. The problem here does not lie on the wrong file path of the ttf font. **I've made use of**

```
game.assetManager.load("font/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf", BitmapFont.class, smallFontParams);
```

instead of

```
game.assetManager.load("smallFont.ttf", BitmapFont.class, smallFontParams);
```

before and it seems to work fine doing so which is contradictory to the statement above.

An **exception is thrown at the update(float delta) method whereas game.assetManager.update() is being called**.

Exception:

```
GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: null (Internal)
at com.bitbench.asternets.Screen.LoadingScreen.update(LoadingScreen.java:84)
at com.bitbench.asternets.Screen.LoadingScreen.render(LoadingScreen.java:67)
```

Comment: make sure file name and path of your file is correct, **file system of Android is case sensitive.**

Comment: as already said the path of my file is correct. I dont ask on stackoverflow if it's a minor issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me days to figure out the problem but here is the answer for people who also face the same problem:

```
    FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter smallFontParams = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
    smallFontParams.fontFileName = "font/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf";
    smallFontParams.fontParameters.size = 40;
    game.assetManager.load("smallFont.ttf", BitmapFont.class, smallFontParams);

    FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter bigFontParams = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
    smallFontParams.fontFileName = "font/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf";
    smallFontParams.fontParameters.size = 85;
    game.assetManager.load("bigFont.ttf", BitmapFont.class, bigFontParams);
```

Using the same FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter and changing it's parameter to create a font will lead you to an exception. So use different FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter in order to create fonts with different parameters! The correct code should be:

```
    FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter smallFontParams = new 
    FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
    smallFontParams.fontFileName = "font/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf";
    smallFontParams.fontParameters.size = 40;
    game.assetManager.load("smallFont.ttf", BitmapFont.class, smallFontParams);

    FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter bigFontParams = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
    bigFontParams.fontFileName = "font/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf";
    bigFontParams.fontParameters.size = 85;
    game.assetManager.load("bigFont.ttf", BitmapFont.class, bigFontParams);
```